# Definition of "of"

Tags: grammar

there is a sentence below.

- I don't watch a lot of TV anymore.

In this sentence, what is the definition of "of"?

there are lots of definition concerning of "of" in dictionary.

but I don't know what is excatly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a preposition, and is used to express the idea of "a part"

We say

> four of the cats

Meaning not all the cats, only four. Or

> Most of the cats

or even

> All of the cats

Meaning the part is actually the 100%

So in your example

> A lot of TV

means "not all TV programs, but many TV programs"

Other languages express partitives in other ways, and may not use a partitive at all in this construction. You will probably find it easier to understand if you think "A lot of" as being a single idiomatic phrase, and not try to understand the meanings of the the separate words.

The phrase "A lot of" means "many" or "much"

Comment: I can understand it. thanks for your answer.

Comment: English learners as not  native speakers always want to understand the way of making meanings of each word, if possible, because they are curretnly using what they memorized in their brains without the image of the REAL meanings: with no confidence